# Why aren't other vaccines combined (like the MMR)?

Tags: vaccination

From [Public Health England](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/mmr-vaccine-dispelling-myths/measles-mumps-rubella-mmr-maintaining-uptake-of-vaccine):

> With single vaccines, children would need 6 separate injections:
>
> - 3 primary doses - 1 measles, 1 mumps, 1 rubella
> - 3 pre-school boosters
>
> Each injection can be uncomfortable and the act of immunisation is sometimes distressing for children.
>
> Single vaccines are less safe than MMR because they leave children vulnerable to dangerous diseases for longer. Giving 3 separate doses at spaced out intervals would mean that, after the first injection, the child still has no immunity to the other 2 diseases.

Given the benefits of combining the measles, mumps, and rubella vaccines into a single MMR (measles, mumps, and rubella) vaccine, why don't we see similar packaging more often? Why aren't other vaccines similarly combined?

Comment: Please re-tag and suggest improvements as appropriate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @KateGregory Are you saying that it is actually a rarity for uncombined childhood vaccines?

Comment: @KateGregory To answer your specific question, I can think of some: Streptococcus pneumoniae, Chickenpox, Hepatitis A and B, Hib (Haemophilus influenzae type B), polio, rotavirus. Please correct me if any are wrong.

Comment: @KateGregory I've never heard of DPTP-Hib, so I am curious: How common is it? (It obviously exists, I did an internet search). Including polio was wrong, my bad. I will list the vaccines and the year of introduction. Could you maybe clarify what your point is? Would it be obvious by looking at years of introduction? Thanks!

Comment: @KateGregory OK thanks. How common is DPTP-Hib?

Comment: @KateGregory Got it

Comment: In the UK, the [6-in-1 vaccination](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/vaccinations/6-in-1-infant-vaccine/) is recommended for all babies at 8, 12 and 16 weeks. It provides immunisation for diphtheria, tetanus, pertussis, hep B, HiB and polio, and thus constitutes a significant proportion of diseases that children are vaccinated against routinely.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the link. Now I can see DPTP-Hib is common, just packaged with Hep B and given a different name.

Comment: @KateGregory I have looked at the introduction dates of all vaccines. It seems to agree with your theory.

Comment: you can answer your own question. It might be helpful to others. And we can clean up this comment thread: I'll delete my other ones now

Comment: @KateGregory I'm hesitant to answer my own question. It was your idea after all. By the way, why did you develop this theory? From somewhere else? Did some research?

Comment: answering your own questions is totally a thing. You've figured out the dates etc. As for how I knew it, I'm just familiar with the childhood vaccination schedule and knew roughly which ones have been introduced in the last 30 years or so and which existed before that.

Comment: @KateGregory Ah, OK, got it. I have much more limited experience with vaccines.

Comment: I'll consider writing my own answer tomorrow, so others can get a chance to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I work in a pediatric office, and we regularly administer combination vaccines to our patients. (Such as Pediarix, Pentacel, ProQuad, etc.) You can check out table 2 in [this link](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/pubs/pinkbook/downloads/appendices/B/us-vaccines.pdf) to see all CDC approved combo vaccines in the U.S.

On a side note, the CDC does not even consider MMR (or DTaP for that matter as well) to be a combo shot as it is hard to find a vaccine for each individual component of those vaccines. ([Source](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/parents/why-vaccinate/combination-vaccines.html))